# Do I have to encode unicode variable before write to file?

Tags: python, python-unicode

I read the "Unicdoe Pain" article days ago. And I keep the "Unicode Sandwich" in mind. 
[image]

Now I have to handle some Chinese and I've got a list

```
chinese = [u'中文', u'你好']
```

Do i need to proceed encoding before writing to file?

```
add_line_break = [word + u'\n' for word in chinese]
encoded_chinese = [word.encode('utf-8') for word in add_line_break]
with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(encoded_chinese)
```

Somehow I find out that in python2. I can do this:

```
chinese = ['中文', '你好']
with open('filename', 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines(chinese)
```

no unicode matter involed. :D

Comment: For reading/writing files, use the [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) function instead with the encoding - the `bytes` (Python2 `str`) type will no longer need to be manually managed within your application when everything will be proper `str` (Python2 `unicode`) types.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that, you could use `io` or `codecs` to open the file with encoding.

```
import io
with io.open('file.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(u'你好')
```

`codecs.open` has the same syntax.

Comment: Better yet, use `io.open`.  It's compatible with Python 3's `open` and aids porting later.

Answer (score 0):

In python3;

```
with open('file.txt, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write('你好')
```

will do just fine.

Comment: Yes. I found out that I can do that in python2 as well. Then why we get unicode type involved in our program? Why not declare byte text everywhere?